# Strategies for detecting contiguous values in an 8x8 matrix

Tags: c++, path-finding, 2d-games

I'm building a puzzle game, similar to Othello, and I'd like to build in a tutorial mode that helps the player learn the game. To do that, I need to detect horizontal, vertical, and diagonal lines of contiguous values (in this case, white or black) to show the player possible next moves they can make...

[image]

I'm building this in C++, but I'm really just interested in general strategies I can use to detect the lines using a 2D matrix (or 1D array if it simplifies things).

My current strategy is pretty straightforward, which makes me suspicious that it's the slowest way to do this...

```
for y = 0 to 7
  for x = 0 to 7
    cell = find the first unoccupied cell (no color)
    inspect the 8 surrounding cells to see if they contain a color
      if so, trace the cells in that direction to see if it forms a line of at least 3 contiguous colors
        if so, store the coords of those cells in a list of detected lines
```

Other ideas?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and in particular [hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) can be helpful.